# What is the python equivalent of setting instances of a class within the __init__() method?

Tags: python

I'd like to send in a list of `dependencies` as part of creating a `DAGNode`: what is the supported way to achieve a similar behavior in python - given it seems this exact syntax were not supported?

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')
class DAGNode(Generic[T]):

    # Apparently the `DAGNode` type does not exist yet so this fails
    def __init__(self, id: T, dependencies: set[DAGNode[T]]):  
        self.id = id
        self.dependencies = dependencies
```

Comment: Add line `from __future__ import annotations` at the beginning. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/

Comment: Hi Michael that's a worthy answer - as an alternative to the also good answer from @Ulisse Rubizzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class does not exist yet you have to reference it including its name between single quote like this

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Set

T = TypeVar('T')
class DAGNode(Generic[T]):

    # Apparently the DAGNode type does not exist yet so this fails
    def __init__(self, type_id: T, dependencies: Set['DAGNode[T]']):  
        self.id = type_id
        self.dependencies = dependencies
```

Notice I used `type_id` instead of id to not shadow the builtin function `id`

Comment: This works.  I don't  follow the comment about `type_id`.  Did you mean to do this `self.type_id = type_id` ?

Comment: ```self.id = type_id``` is ok I've just changed the parameter name id to not shadow builtin function id that returns the memory address of an object

Comment: I'm missing something. Why is the `id: T` in the parameter list supposedly shadowing the id() function, but `self.id` does not?

Comment: Because the function `id()`  belongs to global namespace where also the parameter lives while `self.id` belongs to the namespace of the class. That's the way I see the point

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.7 and later, you can add the line

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

near the beginning of the code. Annotations aren't evaluated then anymore automatically (only valid expression syntax is checked).

For more details see https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/

Comment: This sounds like a tradeoff-  I guess some of the other checks that might be useful would not happen.  I'm trying to ascertain which approach is better  - this one or from @UlisseRubizzo

Comment: @WestCoastProjects Annotations are mainly useful if some external tool like mypy or additional code processes (and therefore validates) it. If the annotation can be evaluated without a NameError or so isn't of much use on its own. Python itself doesn't process the annotation any further (e. g. for type checking).